# Get onclick() content and compare it to current url

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, onclick

Within my navigation i have several links:

```
<div role="button" class="nav-item" 
onclick="submitForm('', 'P_Groups.aspx?IDNavi=97&amp;IDGroups=64');">
Create Topic</div>

<div role="button" class="nav-item" 
onclick="submitForm('', 'P_Groups.aspx?IDNavi=97&amp;IDGroups=65');">
Create Topic</div>
...
```

Goal: An active menu item within the navigation, if the respective site is open.
I cannot give ID's to the links. The `IDGroups=XY` is unique and could be used as identifier.

For this, i need probably three steps:

1. Capture the content `IDGroups=64` within `submitForm` (the 64 is a variable,
   indicating the group).
2. Check whether the `IDGroups=64` is included in the current
   url
3. If yes, add the css class `menuactive` to the parent element of the respective link

Some Explanations would be helpfull since i am quite new to JavaScript.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why can't you give them ID? If you can, data-attributes make more sense
`<div role="button" class="nav-item" data-id="IDGroups=65">` since then you can delegate in an eventListener instead of having inline click handlers

Comment: Unfortunately, those links are generated in visual basic - where i do not have access to. Therefore, i need this work-around.